# Searching Twitter and storing results and replies in MySQL

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have the following code to retrieve pages of tweets containing "SNL":

```
import twitter
import json

twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")

for page in range(11,50):
    k=twitter_search.search(q="SNL",rpp=100,page=page)
    print k
```

Which successfully returns results in JSON format.

With these results - I would like to know how to:

- Store these results in a MySQL DB
- Restrict searches to a specific time period
- Find further tweets which are replies to any of the search results

Comment: Sorry @Anuj about editing over your edit - it appears we were working on it around the same time. To the OP you may have better luck breaking this up into separate questions: ie, first work on storing results, but the rest you'll find quite easily by reading up on the Twitter API developer documents

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```